# Use python-boto and EC2 to brute force

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, boto

As a matter of exercise I would like to do some scientifical computation and Monte Carlo simulations using EC2/python-boto.

For example let's say I have a few subtotals like:

```
a = [53067,
    45412,
    35238,
    34972,
    31551,
    29258,
    28550,
    28044,
    25485,
    21905,
    21597,
    21403,
    20536,
    20013,
    18338,
    17832,
    17186,
    16416,
    14682,
    14595]
```

and then a jagged list of values, which represents monthly data (12 months, 20 value per month):

```
b = [[7043,4567,4386,4247,4426,4562,4107,2986,4022,4733,4738,3295],
    [6090,4396,4382,4201,4409,3960,3315,2342,3034,3762,3858,2597],
    [4445,3525,3432,3338,3396,3134,2774,2205,2909,3682,3415,2457],
    [3998,3037,3203,2952,3122,2743,2564,2165,2904,3217,3324,2141],
    [3438,2762,2975,2817,2401,2489,2479,1975,2811,3107,2862,2130],
    [3027,2588,2865,2376,2392,2326,2327,1911,2383,2918,2646,2078],
    [2878,2323,2861,2294,2289,2206,2179,1863,2340,2829,2312,1560],
    [2862,2289,2853,2258,2256,2142,2021,1653,2164,2705,2308,1470],
    [2727,2046,2452,1972,2214,2117,1868,1569,2098,2436,2284,1462],
    [2664,2007,2005,1970,2145,1799,1825,1482,1971,2285,2053,1417],
    [2575,1987,1972,1865,1808,1780,1822,1391,1792,2161,1962,1411],
    [2417,1979,1957,1675,1783,1778,1795,1334,1767,2057,1928,1396],
    [2225,1860,1774,1631,1743,1762,1713,1315,1762,1921,1732,1391],
    [2152,1700,1760,1624,1722,1489,1694,1228,1722,1790,1648,1315],
    [2053,1621,1740,1533,1618,1445,1440,1119,1377,1598,1585,1299],
    [2033,1485,1607,1422,1469,1273,1415,1036,1314,1547,1534,1286],
    [1887,1452,1478,1361,1434,1265,1410,994,1194,1437,1482,1248],
    [1865,1357,1475,1274,1297,1210,1285,977,1060,1432,1470,1119],
    [1686,1276,1421,1224,1218,993,1128,877,1020,1419,1323,1013],
    [1536,1184,1405,1169,1211,938,1089,785,960,1299,1224,979]]
```

I would like to brute force the following problem using boto: for each value of `a`, find a path through the months that will give the subtotal in `a`.

For example the first value `53067` is obtained by taking:

```
[7043, 4567, 4382, 4202, 4426, 4563, 4108, 2987, 4023, 4733, 4739, 3295]
```

This is quite a hard problem actually to solve for all subtotals, this is why I would like to take the opportunity to learn how to brute force it using EC2 as I could reuse this to do Monte Carlo simulations for example.

I found plenty of tutorials on how to connect and store data, but I did not see anything about distributed computing that is understandable for newcomers.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use EMR (Elastic Map Reduce) to run your computation (essentially hadoop). You can create a cluster of a considerable size using boto if the job requires a lot of processing power.

Then you can write your job in python (assuming you are using python). There are many tutorials around on how to write your map reduce job in python. For example: http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/writing-an-hadoop-mapreduce-program-in-python/

After that you can send your python job to the EMR cluster that you just created and wait for the result.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably just break up the cases into separate arrays, then run each set of cases on a different machine. That's what I'm doing with my flight simulator code. Have two computers in my basement that I remote desktop into. I run a third of my cases on my main desktop, and a third on each basement computer. You can run separate instances simultaneously to increase throughput on a given machine. Writing code that utilizes GPU cores is the next level (I'm not there yet). If you really want to become a monte carlo god that may be the proper path..

Here's a simple solution for brute forcing combinations in Python.

```
index_save = index
for input1 in [0.1,0.2,0.3,...]
    for input2 in [10,20,30,...]
        for input3 in [-0.1,-0.2,-0.3,...]
            index = index_save  #To reset the index and thus all arrays
            while True:
                index = index + 1
                f[index] = *Function of inputs*
                result = *Function of f and inputs*
                if condition_met = true
                    break
            if result > result_best
                result_best = result # Save optimal result
                inputs_best = [input1,input2,input3] # Save optimal input case
```

[How to use nested for loops for brute forcing combinations - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53881221/how-to-use-nested-for-loops-for-brute-forcing-combinations-python/)